# Powershell: print command before executing it

Tags: powershell

I would like to print a command in Powershell before executing it (for debug purposes).

The command is a python command with some variables.
A simple example:

```
> $var = "chocolate"
> python test.py hello $var
Argument list: ['test.py', 'hello', 'chocolate']
```

I would like to print the command with the content of the variable before running it. So print something like:

```
python test.py hello chocolate
```

I tried using `Set-PSDebug` cmdlet but it doesn't resolve the `$var` variable:

```
> $var="chocolate"
> Set-PSDebug -trace 1
> python test.py hello $var
    1+ >>>>> python test.py hello $var
Argument list: ['test.py', 'hello', 'chocolate']
```

(I also tried with `-trace 2`, not successful either)

Is there a way to print the command with the variable in it before executing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try saving your command off as a variable. This will give you the ability to print the command but doesn't actually run the command.

```
PS T:\> $var = "hello"
PS T:\> cmd /c "echo $var"
hello
PS T:\> $test = "cmd /c 'echo $var'"

PS T:\> $test
cmd /c 'echo hello'
```